# How remove the spacing around` \cdot`?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, amsfonts

[image]

In some mathematical expressions, I need to place `\cdot` but also remove the space around it

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    $|\cdot|$

\end{document}
```

Comment: tray $|{\cdot}|$ ?

Comment: You can try `{\cdot}` instead of `\cdot`. It won't remove *all* space, but as an 'ord' there will generally be less space than usual.

Comment: It does not work at all. Same result

Comment: In your example `|\cdot|` and `|{\cdot}|` give vastly different results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3oPz.png (top is `|\cdot|`, bottom is `|{\cdot}|`). If you see a different result, please post a suitable MWE. Note that MathJax and friends may or may not follow these TeX rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally use `\lvert` and `\rvert` for the bars denoting absolute value/modulus.

I suggest to define

```
\newcommand{\blank}{{\mspace{1mu}\cdot\mspace{1mu}}}
```

for the centered dot used as a signpost. You're not using the centered dot in its proper meaning, so it's best to define another name for it. And you can later decide how to eventually typeset it: maybe your coauthor prefers a dash instead of the centered dot…

[image]

The last two examples show the main reason why `\lvert...\rvert` is better than `|...|`.

Comment: This answers my question. However, why putting the defined command between curly brackets works to minimize the space while removing them does not?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh `|` is considered as an ordinary symbol, so with `|\cdot|` you get the same spacing around the dot as in `1\cdot2`, because `\cdot` is a binary operation symbol. If you brace it, it becomes ordinary, so TeX adds no space around it. For the same reason I added braces in the definition of `\blank`, so it's treated as an ordinary symbol (which it is).

Answer (score 2):

Please compare the results of the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

$|\cdot|$, $\abs{\cdot}$, $|{\cdot}|$, 

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is up to you which of solution you will use (the second or the third as I proposed in my comment)

Comment: Very very nice the answer...and the your original g..ravatar :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much for compliment !

Answer (score 0):

It's worth knowing a little about how spacing in math mode works. Every character in math mode is given a class. There are ord symbols (most symbols), binary operators (+, -, `\cdot`, among others), relations, openings and closings.

In this case, we're dealing with a binary operator which appears between two ordinary symbols. In that case, it gets spaced as if we're writing *a* + *b* where the two instances of | act like the *a* and *b* while `\cdot` acts as +. But at the beginning of a formula, a binary operator does not get the spacing since it's assumed that you're writing something like -2 where there should not be space between the - and the 2.¹

The reason that `\abs{\cdot}` works is that it turns the enclosing |s into an opening and a closing. These get the same spacing as ordinary symbols with one key difference: After a open or before a close, we don't get the spacing for a binary operation so that we can write things like (-*x* + 1) and get the correct spacing.²

On the other hand, writing `{\cdot}` effectively erases the binary operator status of `\cdot` (enclosing anything in braces causes the entire contents to be treated as a single ordinary symbol for spacing purposes. Empty braces are an invisible sizeless ordinary symbol for use in writing things like `{} + 3` as mentioned in footnote 1 below).

---

1. This is also why, when writing a multiline display, you'll put `{}` before a binary operation at the beginning of the line.
2. I've never seen an expression like (*a*-) in anything that I've read, but there's also not bin operation spacing around the minus in that case either.